# Thunderbird default to add new contacts to Personal Address Book?

Tags: thunderbird

As a relatively new user of Thunderbird 3, I've noticed that it nicely adds new e-mails to the "Collected Addresses" address book.

When I try editing those added addresses and move them into lists in my Personal Address Book, the contacts lose all the information I entered except one e-mail field!

Is there a way for Thunderbird to add new contacts directly into the Personal Address Book instead of Collected Addresses?

Comment: see if this method helps http://email.about.com/od/mozillathunderbirdtips/qt/Export_Contacts_from_the_Mozilla_Thunderbird_Address_Book.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Tools > Options > Composition > Addressing

There is a checkbox option for **Automatically add outgoing e-mail addresses to my**. Make sure this box is checked.

Change the option from **Collected Addresses** to **Personal Address Book.**

This will now save all contacts to the Personal Address Book when sending out emails.